# Why isn't height 100% extend the div completely to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want `#f8f8f8` to extend until the bottom of the page. I tried adding `height: 100%;` to `.tab-content` but nothing happened.

Any suggestions?

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.tab-container {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.tab-content {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  height: 100%; /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class="vreditor-sdk">
  <div class="building">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="i-tab">
      <div class="tab-container">
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        Test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the relation between the title of the question and the content?

Comment: `html,body {height:100%; width:100%}`

Comment: `<div class="tab-container>` missing `"`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because title doesnt match the question and seems to be not searched well before asking

Comment: @NoobEditor Oh, sorry I made a mistake, but fixed it.

Comment: @alex : take some time out to study [div behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/0cutnj05/) - how html `div`s work.

Comment: .building {height: 100vh}

.itab {
  height: 100%}

.tab-content {
  height: 100%}

Comment: @NoobEditor The question is clear, background not reaching bottom is just the proof that 100% height given to a div is not reaching bottom of page (as per his understanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css when you give height as percentage, it will take that percentage of parent height.

Giving `height: 100%;` to `.tab-content` means it takes `100%` height of `.itab` not the page. So if you want your `.tab-content` to cover whole page, your `.itab` needs to cover the whole page first. Same happens with every direct parent until you reach `html` element.

So your fix should be

```
html, body, .vreditor-sdk, .building, .itab, .tab-content {
    height: 100%:
}
```

html takes 100% height of the page, body takes 100% height of html which is same as page height and so on...

This is how your page height reaches your `.tab-content`

Answer (score 1):

put background -color property in i-tab class

```
.i-tab { 
background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

and remove it from tab-content class.

Comment: `.i-tab` isn't reaching the bottom, either.

Comment: @alex not saying its a solution `color: #fff` `;` after it?? so many syntax issues 
 dude!

Comment: then try making it( #f8f8f8) the body background and change the background of the divs you want